# Swift 3 - Error while playing sound on splashscreen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer, exc-bad-access

I work on Xcode 8, Swift 3.

I'm trying to do a code to play a sound just after the app launched. I putted it into the function (in AppDelegate) :

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {}
```

And so here's my code :

```
var opening_sound = AVAudioPlayer()
```

and after :

```
let Nt = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "opp", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do {
            opening_sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: Nt)
            opening_sound.prepareToPlay()

        } catch {print("Error")}

        opening_sound.play()
```

Of course I import AVFundation.

When running I get in console "Error" and then on the line `opening_sound.play()` I get "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address= 0x48).

I tried running it with zombie objects activated but no answer.

EDIT: 
Thanks for your answers. In reply to @silicon_valley :

the error I get is The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)

I just also had : objc[31817]: Class _NSZombie___NSArrayM is implemented in both ?? (0x618000047c80) and ?? (0x618000047cb0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. with zombies allowed.

I tried what you said @Pierce but it doesn't work because AVAudioplayer can't be an optional value. If I write `... = AVAudioplayer?` I've the choice between `AVAudioplayer?()` that end up with "Cannot invoke initialiser for type 'AVAudioPlayer?' with no argument". Or if I write `AVAudioPlayer?.self` the code after doesn't run properly.

So, given that I can initiate opening_sound as an optional value this :

```
if let Nt = Nt {
    self.opening_sound = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: Nt)
}
```

doesn't work and so is the code.

I think the problem is dealing with the main thread but I can't see it. Of course "opp.mp3" is in the main bundle.

EDIT: Thank to @Pierce answer (sorry, I didn't read properly) I got this :

```
var opening_sound: AVAudioPlayer?
```

...

```
let Nt: URL? = URL(fileURLWithPath: (Bundle.main.path(forResource: "opp", ofType: "mp3"))!)
        if let Nt = Nt {
            self.opening_sound = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: Nt)
        }

        playOpeningSound()
```

...

```
 func playOpeningSound() {
        if let opening_sound = opening_sound {
            if opening_sound.isPlaying {
                opening_sound.pause()
            }
            opening_sound.currentTime = 0
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                opening_sound.play()
            }

        }
```

And I've no error. But no sound comes out...!
Thank for your help !

Comment: What is the error you get in the catch? If you replace `catch {print("Error")}` with `catch let error { print(error.localizedDescription) }` you'll get the reason of the crash. Also, you shouldn't call 'play' if there was an error in the do...catch block.

Comment: @VincentS - I added an answer that should work if you have your sound file name and extension typed properly. How you've written it, you should make sure you have a file called `opp.mp3` in your main bundle. Hopefully it will help

Comment: I apologize Vincent. Please check my updated answer. I forgot to cast `Nt` as an optional `URL`. You need to say `let Nt:URL? ...`

Comment: Check my updated answer it should work now.

Comment: Glad it works for you! Please accept my answer as correct since it worked!

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! No errors but no sound is playing... Would you know why..? @Pierce

Comment: @VincentS - I'm sorry I misread this time. I thought you said sound WAS playing

Comment: Make sure the device you're testing on, that the physical silent switch is turned off. That's one thing. The other would be to make sure everything with the code worked. Put a breakpoint at the very beginning of the `playOpeningSound` method, and make sure you can step all the way through

Comment: I added an updated `print` command in my answer for the `playOpeningSound` method. Please insert that in your code, run the app and tell me if it prints to the console

Comment: Ok no problem. I added the 'print' command and nothing's printed.. Confusing.

Comment: @VincentS - what that tells me is that `opening_sound` is still `nil` when you try to play it. Because when we do the conditional check `if let opening_sound = opening_sound`, it only proceeds further if it's not `nil`. Considering that nothing is printing, I assume it's still nil

Comment: @VincentS - Try this to make sure you've copied the sound file properly. First right click on the `opp.mp3` file in your project and just say Delete->Move to Trash. Then add it to your project again by dragging and dropping it in your project folder while in Xcode. Xcode will have a prompt that asks you "Copy Items if Needed" Make sure that is checked. Once you've done that re-build and run the project

Comment: @Pierce Yes you're probably right, it's nil. The code can find the file otherwise it gives a fatal error. So it's not a problem dealing with that. I'm lost.

Comment: @VincentS - I edited my code again to contain a `do try catch` like you originally had. Please put this in your code so you can tell me if an error prints out when instantiating `AVAudioPlayer` and if so, what the error is

Comment: @Pierce thank a lot for your work. I tried what you gave to me but now I have "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION..." "Fatal error: unexpedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the best way to play a song is to do it asynchronously. `prepareToPlay` never seems to work properly for me, and it doesn't solve the problem of causing a pause in the UI the first time you play it. Try something similar to this:

Instantiate the AVAudioPlayer, make `opening_sound` optional

```
var opening_sound: AVAudioPlayer?

let Nt:URL? = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "opp", ofType: "mp3")!)
if let Nt = Nt {
    do {
      self.opening_sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: Nt)
       } catch { 
          print(error) 
       }
}

playOpeningSound()
```

Play sound method:

```
func playOpeningSound() {
    if let opening_sound = opening_sound {
        if opening_sound.isPlaying {
            opening_sound.pause()
        }
        opening_sound.currentTime = 0
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            opening_sound.play()
            print("Sound should be playing")
        }
    }
}
```